# How to write mongo pipeline

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to write a mongo pipeline to select mongodb documents as show in the function below.
The mongo.Pipeline is showing "missing type in composite literal".
I am trying to aggregate all the ipv4Addresses in documents that match nfType based on the highest capacity. Am using mongo-driver.
Can anyone help me solve the mongo.Pipeline problem.

```
func (m *NfInstanceDataAccess) FindNFinstanceInfoUsingTACWithCapacity(preferredNfInstances string, tac string) ([]doc, bool) {

    var nfInstance []doc
    pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{{{"$match", bson.M{{"nfType", preferredNfInstances}}}},
        {{"$unwind", "$ipv4Addresses"}},
        {{"$group", bson.M{
            {"_id": "$capacity"},
            {"ipv4Addresses": bson.M{
                {"$addToSet", "$ipv4Addresses"},
            }},
        }}},
        {{"$sort", bson.M{
            {"_id", 1},
        }}},
        {{"$limit", 1}},
    }
    cursor, err := db.Collection(COLLECTION).Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
    defer cursor.Close(context.Background())

    err = cursor.All(ctx, &nfInstance)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Unable to perform NRF discovery search: %s", err.Error())
    }
    if err := cursor.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Cursor error in NRF discovery search: %s", err.Error())
    }
    return nfInstance, true
}
```

Thethe pipeline below work using the mongo command line. And I would like to have a bson.M form of it. Any help.

```
db.nnfdb.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "nfType": "AMF"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$ipv4Addresses"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$capacity",
      "ipv4Addresses": {
        "$addToSet": "$ipv4Addresses"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

Comment: bson.M is a map, so a literal will look like `bson.M{"key":"value"}`. Your pipeline appears to be written for `bson.D`, which uses the syntax you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The mongo.Pipeline is showing "missing type in composite literal"

Your aggregation pipeline is mixing up the syntax of [bson.D](https://pkg.go.dev/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#D) and [bson.M](https://pkg.go.dev/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M). For example, `bson.D` is:

```
bson.D{{ "a", 1 }, { "b", true }}
```

while `bson.M` is as below:

```
bson.M{ "a": 1, "b": true }
```

Please note the number of brackets `{` , `}` and also the comma and semicolon.

For MongoDB Aggregation pipeline where sometimes order matters, it is safer and recommended to use `bson.D` instead of `bson.M`. Using this knowledge, below is the fixed up aggregation pipeline that you have provided.

```
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$match", bson.D{{"nfType", preferredNfInstances}}}},
    {{"$unwind", "$ipv4Addresses"}},
    {{"$group", bson.D{
        {"_id", "$capacity"},
        {"ipv4Addresses", bson.D{
            {"$addToSet", "$ipv4Addresses"},
        }},
    }}},
    {{"$sort", bson.D{
        {"_id", 1},
    }}},
    {{"$limit", 1}},
}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to use `bson.M` see below example:

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"nfType": preferredNfInstances}},
    bson.M{"$unwind": "$ipv4Addresses"},
    bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
        "_id": "$capacity",
        "ipv4Addresses": bson.M{
            "$addToSet": "$ipv4Addresses",
        },
    }},
    bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{
        "_id": 1,
    }},
    bson.M{"$limit": 1},
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but i would like to have the bson.M form of the pipleline. I have pasted the aggregation that work using the mongo command line. Can you help write the bson.M form of it.

Comment: Hi @samcreg, I've added the example for `bson.M` as well. In the future, please remember that if you're asking a question in StackOverflow, you should accompany that with an attempt that you've tried.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that.